# Редирект на домен с кириллицей

Tags: java, http, get, редирект, кириллица

Имеется следующая задача: получить исходный код страницы, расположенной по адресу http://rp5.ru/archive.php?wmo_id=27612.

Проблема в том, что при переходе по этой ссылке происходит редирект на адрес, в котором содержится кириллица.

Пробовал выполнить данную задачу с помощью:

1. HttpURLConnection
2. Apache http client
3. JSoup

Во всех трех случаях появляются ошибки во время выполнения. Например, при помощи JSoup:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://rp5.ru/archive.php?wmo_id=27612").get();
    System.out.println(doc.title());
    }
}
```

Получаю:

> Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=400, URL=http://m.rp5.ru?q=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0+%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0&?lang=ru
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:537)
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:534)
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:534)
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:534)
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
>       at com.selw.Main.main(Main.java:11)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать данную задачу. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня почему-то результат зависит от текущей кодировки файлов по умолчанию. Видимо, Jsoup закладывается на неё при редиректе. Попробуйте выставить явно:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("file.encoding", "cp1251");
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://rp5.ru/archive.php?wmo_id=27612").get();
    System.out.println(doc.title());
}
```

Любопытно, что при кодировке `"utf-16"` ошибки нет, но получается другая страница.

Comment: Такое происходит потому что сервер rp5.ru отдает некорректный заголовок. Не удивлюсь, если этот редирект и в браузерах работает только на русской винде.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, может заголовок некорректный, но и в Jsoup косяк: нельзя закладываться на кодировку по умолчанию вообще. Как минимум, это должно настраиваться средствами самого Jsoup, но я не нашёл такой настройки (может, плохо искал, конечно).

Comment: Разумеется, это косяк Jsoup. Я лишь объяснил, откуда у него ноги растут..

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте применить класс URLDecoder к адресу на кириллице.

Comment: Была такая мысль, но я не разобрался, как получить адрес, на который идет редирект.

Совет выше помог, вопрос более не актуален.